# Polymer, already registered (Polymer) prototype when declared imperatively

Tags: javascript, polymer, web-component, prototype-programming

I am trying to instantiate and append a new Polymer custom element on function call (called on drag-drop event).

My code is as follows:

```
var d = workspaceElem(dragInfo.objRef);
dropTarget.appendChild(d);

function workspaceElem(ref){
      Polymer('workspace-elem', {
        objRef: ref
      });
      var elem = document.createElement('div');
      elem.innerHTML = '<polymer-element name="workspace-elem" noscript>\
      <template>\
      <div>{{objRef.ref.innerText}}</div>\
      </tempate>\
      </polymer-element>'

      return elem;
    }
```

This code works fine the first time, however an error is thrown for all other objects.

> Uncaught Already registered (Polymer) prototype for element
>   workspace-elem

How do I instantiate a new element everytime?  Is it possible to define this element declaratively in a new file, import the element, then instantiate it imperatively?  If so, how so?

Any assistance appreciated thanks!

Comment: You want to insert the `<polymer-element name="workspace-elem">..` only once. However, the `<workspace-elem></workspace-elem` can be inserted multiple times

Comment: Ah gotcha, so .innerHTML="<workspace-elem></workspace-elem>" will work.  Thanks!